# Retrieve paytoshi.org Balance with VBA and Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I got this HTML code extract from the web site paytoshi.org:

```
        <table class="table keyvalue-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="kv-key"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin kv-icon kv-icon-primary"></i> Current*</td>
                    <td class="kv-value">0.00001578</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="kv-key"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin kv-icon kv-icon-primary"></i> Total Paid</td>
                    <td class="kv-value">0.00000000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="kv-key"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin kv-icon kv-icon-secondary"></i> Revenue last 24h</td>
                    <td class="kv-value">0.00000000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="kv-key"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin kv-icon kv-icon-secondary"></i> Revenue last week</td>
                    <td class="kv-value">0.00000000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="kv-key"><i class="fa fa-exchange kv-icon kv-icon-success"></i> Total Payouts</td>
                    <td class="kv-value">27</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I need to retrieve ONLY the Current* balance (in the code posted above i need ONLY this data: 0.00001578 and i want to put it in the Worksheets("Balance").Range("A1").

I tried this code but without sucess:

```
    ' Imposta le variabili.
    Dim strIndirizzoWeb, strIndirizzoBitcoin As String
    ' InternetExplorer.Application.
    Dim objIE As Object
    ' HTMLDocument.
    Dim objHTML As Object
    ' IHTMLElementCollection.
    Dim objLista As Object
    ' IHTMLElement.
    Dim objL As Object
    ' Contatori ciclo For e Range.
    Dim intF, intR As Integer
    ' Contatore.
    Dim intX As Integer

    ' Crea l'oggetto IE.
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ' Mette nelle celle "No" per indicare che si stanno aggiornando i dati.
    Worksheets("Saldi").Range("M15:M17").Value = "No"
    ' Ho 3 microwallet in Paytoshi.
    For intF = 0 To 2
        With objIE
            ' Nasconde IE.
            .Visible = False
            ' Visualizza IE.
            .Visible = True
            intR = 15 + intF
            ' Inserisce nell'indirizzo web l'indirizzo del microwallet preso dal foglio Saldi.
            .Navigate "https://paytoshi.org/" & Worksheets("Saldi").Range("N" & intR & "").Value & "/balance"
            ' Attende fino a che IE non ha finito di leggere la pagina.
            Do Until .readyState = 4
                Application.StatusBar = "Sto scaricando le informazioni. Attendere, prego..."
                DoEvents
            Loop
            ' Reimposto la StatusBar come in origine.
            Application.StatusBar = "Pronto"
            Set objHTML = .document
            Do Until objHTML.readyState = "complete"
                DoEvents
            Loop
            ' Attende 5 secondi.
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        End With
         ' Restituisce la lista degli elementi <TD>.
        Set objLista = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each objL In objLista
            Debug.Print objL.innerText
            ' Si accerta che l'elemento sia chiamato "ajax-data data-pending".
            If InStr(1, objL.innerText, "Current*") > 0 Then

                Worksheets("Saldi").Range("P" & intR & "").Value = objL.innerText
            End If
        Next
        Worksheets("Saldi").Range("M" & intR & "").Value = "Ok"
        Application.StatusBar = "Informazioni Faucetbox per il MicroWallet " & Worksheets("Saldi").Range("N" & intR & "").Value & " scaricate."
    Next intF
```

Comment: @JordanDoyle : i try this:  No sorry.... how can i add a vba code at my question too?

Comment: Please edit your question to describe exactly what the problem is with you code: desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the inner text of the wrong element.  Check the entire row instead of the cell:

```
    Set objLista = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each objL In objLista
        ' Si accerta che l'elemento sia chiamato "ajax-data data-pending".
        If InStr(1, objL.innerText, "Current*") > 0 Then
            Dim balance As Double
            balance = Val(Replace(objL.innerText, "Current*", vbNullString))
            Worksheets("Saldi").Range("P" & intR & "").Value = balance
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS query:**

You can use a CSS selector of `table.keyvalue-table td`. This says elements with `td` tag inside `table keyvalue-table`

---

**CSS query (sample of matched elements):**

[image: sample]

---

**VBA:**

There are a collection of matching elements. Theses are retrieved by applying the CSS selector using `querySelectorAll` method of `document`. You then index into the 0 based nodeList by position to get the element as index 1.

```
Debug.Print objIE.document.querySelectorAll("table.keyvalue-table td")(1).innerText
```

Sometimes the syntax varies slightly:

```
Debug.Print objIE.document.querySelectorAll("table.keyvalue-table td").Item(1).innerText
```